# Using a CustomExpression in a DynamicJasper chart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I have a project using DynamicJasper to create reports. It works fine so far, but when I wanted to add a chart to a previously functional report I run into issues.

I keep getting this:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :
>        1. Field not found : customExpression_for_Ganancia
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:258)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:140)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)
>       at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:519)
>       at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:279)
>       at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:232)

Ganancia being the only column in the chart that is a CustomExpression. If I don't add this column as a series to the chart, the chart renders properly. It seems the chart doesn't play well with expressions...

A snippet from my code:

```
private DynamicReport buildSalesReport() throws ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException, ChartBuilderException {

    DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();

    drb.setReportName("Reporte de Ventas")
        .setTitle("Reporte de ventas")
        .setSubtitle("Este reporte fue generado el " + new Date())
        .setPrintColumnNames(false)
        .setIgnorePagination(true)
        .setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        .setUseFullPageWidth(true);

    Style groupOneStyle = new Style();
            groupOneStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_BIG);
            groupOneStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.LEFT);
            groupOneStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);

    AbstractColumn columnDisplayName = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("bookingType.displayName", String.class.getName())
            .setTitle("Tipo").setWidth(new Integer(40))
            .setStyle(groupOneStyle)
            .build();

    AbstractColumn columnDestiny = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("bookedObject.destiny", String.class.getName())
            .setTitle("Destino").setWidth(new Integer(40))
            .build();

    Style priceStyle = new Style();
    priceStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);

    AbstractColumn columnCurrency = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("bookedObject.currency.displayName", String.class.getName())
            .setTitle("Cotizacion").setWidth(new Integer(5))
            .setShowText(false)
            .build();

    Style footerStyle = new Style();
            footerStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_MEDIUM);
            footerStyle.setBorderTop(Border.THIN);
            footerStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);
            footerStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);

    AbstractColumn columnPrice = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("bookedObject.price", Double.class.getName())
            .setStyle(priceStyle)
            .setPattern("$ 0.00")
            .setTitle("Precio").setWidth(new Integer(25))
            .build();

    AbstractColumn columnCount = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("count", Integer.class.getName())
            .setStyle(priceStyle)
            .setTitle("Cantidad").setWidth(new Integer(25))
            .build();

    columnCount.setName("Cantidad");

    AbstractColumn columnProfit = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
        .setCustomExpression(this.getProfitExpression())
        .setStyle(priceStyle)
        .setTitle("Ganancia").setWidth(new Integer(20))
        .setPattern("$ 0.00")
        .build();

    columnProfit.setName("Ganancia");

    GroupBuilder groupBookingTypeBuilder = new GroupBuilder();
    DJGroup groupBookingType =
        groupBookingTypeBuilder.setCriteriaColumn((PropertyColumn) columnDisplayName)
            .setGroupLayout(GroupLayout.VALUE_IN_HEADER_WITH_HEADERS_AND_COLUMN_NAME)
            .build();

    GroupBuilder groupCurrencyBuilder = new GroupBuilder();
    DJGroup groupCurrency =
        groupCurrencyBuilder.setCriteriaColumn((PropertyColumn) columnCurrency)
            .addFooterVariable(columnCount,DJCalculation.SUM,footerStyle)
            .addFooterVariable(columnProfit,DJCalculation.SUM,footerStyle)
            .setGroupLayout(GroupLayout.VALUE_IN_HEADER)
            .build();

    drb.addColumn(columnDisplayName)
        .addColumn(columnCurrency)
        .addColumn(columnDestiny)
        .addColumn(columnCount)
        .addColumn(columnPrice)
        .addColumn(columnProfit)
        .addGroup(groupBookingType)
        .addGroup(groupCurrency)
        .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true);

    DJAxisFormat categoryAxisFormat = new DJAxisFormat("Destino");
    categoryAxisFormat.setLabelFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
    categoryAxisFormat.setLabelColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    categoryAxisFormat.setTickLabelFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
    categoryAxisFormat.setTickLabelColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    categoryAxisFormat.setTickLabelMask("");
    categoryAxisFormat.setLineColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    DJAxisFormat valueAxisFormat = new DJAxisFormat("Ventas / Ingresos");
    valueAxisFormat.setLabelFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
    valueAxisFormat.setLabelColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    valueAxisFormat.setTickLabelFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
    valueAxisFormat.setTickLabelColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    valueAxisFormat.setTickLabelMask("#,##0");
    valueAxisFormat.setLineColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    DJChart djChart = new DJBarChartBuilder()
            //chart
            .setX(20)
            .setY(10)
            .setWidth(500)
            .setHeight(250)
            .setCentered(false)
            .setBackColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
            .setShowLegend(true)
            .setPosition(DJChartOptions.POSITION_FOOTER)
            .setTitle(new StringExpression() {
                @Override
                public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
                    return variables.get("bookingType.displayName");
                }
            })
            .setTitleColor(Color.DARK_GRAY)
            .setTitleFont(Font.ARIAL_BIG_BOLD)
            .setSubtitle("subtitle")
            .setSubtitleColor(Color.DARK_GRAY)
            .setSubtitleFont(Font.COURIER_NEW_BIG_BOLD)
            .setLegendColor(Color.DARK_GRAY)
            .setLegendFont(Font.COURIER_NEW_MEDIUM_BOLD)
            .setLegendBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setLegendPosition(DJChartOptions.EDGE_BOTTOM)
            .setTitlePosition(DJChartOptions.EDGE_TOP)
            .setLineStyle(DJChartOptions.LINE_STYLE_DOTTED)
            .setLineWidth(1)
            .setLineColor(Color.DARK_GRAY)
            .setPadding(5)
            //dataset
            .setCategory((PropertyColumn) columnDestiny)
            .addSerie(columnCount, "Cantidad")
            .addSerie(columnProfit, "Ganancia") // IF I COMMENT THIS LINE THE CHART IS RENDERED
            //plot
            .setCategoryAxisFormat(categoryAxisFormat)
            .setValueAxisFormat(valueAxisFormat)
            .build();

    drb.addChart(djChart);

    HashMap vars = new HashMap();
    vars.put(columnCount, new JRDesignVariable());
    vars.put(columnProfit, new JRDesignVariable());
    JRDesignGroup group = new JRDesignGroup();
    djChart.transform(new DynamicJasperDesign(), "", group, group, vars, 0);

    DynamicReport dr = drb.build();

    return dr;
}

public JasperPrint getJasperPrint(String status, String userOwner,
            String hourFrom, String hourTo, String dateFrom, String dateTo)
        throws ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException, JRException, ChartBuilderException {

    DynamicReport dr = this.buildSalesReport();

    JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
            this.bookService.getReportBooks(status, userOwner, hourFrom, hourTo, dateFrom, dateTo));

    return DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr , new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds);
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private CustomExpression getProfitExpression() {
    return new CustomExpression() {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
            Double amount = (Integer)fields.get("count") * (Double)fields.get("bookedObject.price");
            return amount;
        }

        @Override
        public String getClassName() {
            return Double.class.getName();
        }
    };
```

As I said, the report is shown properly without the chart, with the chart, it fails only if the expression column is included as a series.

Any ideas are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pushed the change for DJ 4.0.1 in commit 05243a3

Sometime today will also push for DJ 3.X

Comment: DJ version 3.2.4 fixes the problem also: commit is 6818489 soon the release in sourceforge

Comment: Awesome! I would have not expected the response to arrive after over a year, least of all to be fixed on the project itself :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this very same problem doing the following:

1. Set the "fieldDescription" of your column.
2. Re-write the Method "protected Map registerChartVariable(ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.chart.DJChart chart)" of class AbstractLayoutManager":

> JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
>
> ```
> String property =  ((PropertyColumn) col).getFieldDescription();
> ```
>
> // ((PropertyColumn) col).getColumnProperty().getProperty();
>
> ```
> expression.setText("$F{" +  property  + "}");
> expression.setValueClass(clazz);
> ```

3 . As you have already figured out, you'll have to create your own LayoutManager for this task.
4 . This may not be the best solution, it is just an example how to fill the gap of DynamicJasper.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but I had a slightly different solution.  There are different types of Column classes, but only the `PropertyColumn` class is supported in the `AbstractLayoutManager` for charts.  I found out that when you use a `CustomExpression`, the underlying `Column` class that is used is an `ExpressionColumn`.  So, I modified the "protected Map `registerChartVariable()` method in the `ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.AbstractLayoutManager` to support `ExpressionColumn`.

I changed the following 3 lines of code in that method:

```
JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setText("$F{" + ((PropertyColumn) col).getColumnProperty().getProperty()  + "}");
expression.setValueClass(clazz);
```

To the following:

```
if (col instanceof ExpressionColumn) {
    ExpressionColumn expCol = (ExpressionColumn) col;
    expression.setText(expCol.getTextForExpression());
    expression.setValueClassName(expCol.getExpression().getClassName());
} else {
    expression.setText("$F{" + ((PropertyColumn) col).getColumnProperty().getProperty()  + "}");
    expression.setValueClass(clazz);
}
```

This resolved the problem for me and I no longer get the "**Field not found**" message.